# Override Title value in dexterity type

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I have a custom type in dexterity (schema driven) without title or description fields.

```
class IAnimal(model.Schema):
    name = schema.TextLine(title=_(u"Name"),required=True,)
    specie = schema.Choice(title=_(u"Specie"),vocabulary=animalSpecies)
    weight = schema.TextLine(title=_(u"Weight"))
    (etc)
```

I really don't need the title field on my model, but when I create some content, on folder listing is displaying:

```
— by admin — last modified Oct 17, 2015 02:27 PM
```

I created this product with mr.bob and didn't override any forms yet. This can be accomplished by override any forms, a custom behavior (like plone.app.content.interfaces.INameFromTitle) or what?

I just want the "name" field as "title" without changing "name" for "title", even that I must have to hide the "title" field in the model.

Looking at some old archetypes products, it was a method like:

```
def at_post_create_script(self):
    title = self.name
    plone_utils = getToolByName(self, 'plone_utils', None)
    new_id = plone_utils.normalizeString(title)
    self.setTitle(new_id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't get why you can't simply provide a "title" field named "Name" (easiest way), however you can also override the `title` attribute and `Title` method of the base class.

If you used mr.bob you probably don't have a **base class** you can customize.
Check your type definition XML: in the `klass` property you probably have `plone.dexterity.content.Item`. Change it to a new dexterity base class you must add to you product (example: https://github.com/collective/wildcard.media/blob/84b82994dc424fe40b92b1c9af8d48edb558a78d/wildcard/media/content.py#L6)

When you have the base class you can add the `Title` method and a `title` attribute, something like:

```
class MyType(Item):
    implements(IMyType)

    def Title(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def title(self)
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks @keul, worked like a charm! I'm working on a migration using collective.transmogrify, so on the old plone site i don't have 'title' field. I've also checked https://github.com/ploneintranet/ploneintranet/blob/master/src/ploneintranet/todo/content/todo.py#L17 as an example.